# how to avoid modal hide when clicking body

Tags: jquery, uikit, getuikit

I'm modifying a site which has modal with UIKit, that's the generic modal and how I open it, in this case, I want to hide the button.

```
     <div id="modal_generic" class="uk-modal generic_modal uk-open" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
            <h4 class="uk-h4">text</h4>
            <div class="wrap_buttons_accept_input_file uk-width-1-1">
                <a class="uk-button uk-button-link uk-button-small uk-modal-close btn_close_form"">CLOSE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


  $('#modal_generic').find('h4').text('modal text');
  $('#modal_generic .uk-form').hide();
  $('.btn_close_form').hide();
  $.UIkit.modal('#modal_generic').show();
```

That's works fine, but this modal can't be hidden, and it happen when clicking outside, I can't find how to do it.

My try:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

But not working.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already not hiding on body click. Just don't show it manually.

```js
$('#modal_generic').find('h4').text('modal text');
$('#modal_generic .uk-form').hide();
$('.btn_close_form').hide();
//var modal = UIkit.modal("#modal_generic");
//console.log(modal.defaults.bgclose = false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/uikit.js"></script>
<div id="modal_generic" class="uk-modal generic_modal uk-open" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; overflow-y: scroll;" data-uk-modal="{target:'#ID',bgclose:false}">
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <h4 class="uk-h4">text</h4>
    <div class="wrap_buttons_accept_input_file uk-width-1-1">
      <a class="uk-button uk-button-link uk-button-small uk-modal-close btn_close_form" ">CLOSE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```